# Are questions getting deleted too easily?

Tags: discussion

I believe I asked a question about whether in general, it is an evolutionary stable strategy in nature for all the individuals to get just barely enough food to eat, and have the population size balanced by the rate of starvation, not that death by old age doesn't occur. Now I can't find it in my profile anymore. I think now I would know how to ask it again and make it clear. I would write in the body of the question that I cannot figure out an algorithm for determining what type of answer I would find useful but have a general idea of what I'm looking for, and that I'm looking for an answer by an expert who is able to function as if they are a future self of me and use their discretion on how to write an answer that appears good to them, just like sometimes when somebody is working on something, they trust their future self to use their discretion on how to continue it. Also, when questions get deleted, people never learn that somebody had a question like that and miss out on valuable feedback.

Then if I got an answer to that question, I might use it to ask another question. I might link my question [Why haven't prey evolved the ability to always outrun their predators?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/45342/why-havent-prey-evolved-the-ability-to-always-outrun-their-predators) in that question and make the question whether the tendency to get just barely enough food to eat and the evolutionary pressure to conserve energy is the reason.

I know the fact that it was me and not somebody else who originally had it instinctively come to them that that question is a good question is a sign that fewer people think it's good, and the fact that so few people think it is a sign that they have evidence giving them a reason to think it and it is a good idea for me to take their experience into account to some extent.

Answer (score 3):

The question you refer to received 4 downvotes. It was deleted by the "[Roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=roomba)", the friendly name SE has given to the script which removes old questions without good answers and with neutral/negative score.

There is an old request on the Main Meta for all deleted questions to be visible to the users who posted them, but the request was denied. I'm not weighing in either way, but the discussion is here if you'd like to review it:

[Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)?

(if this were to change, it would be a site-wide change, not a specific change at Biology.SE)

However, you should be able to still find your own deleted questions if you have a link to them, you can try this one (moderators and 10K rep users can also see it):

https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/93789/

My biggest issues with your question were that it was long and rambling and that you were using the term "evolutionarily stable strategy" but did not seem to understand what this term meant. That's usually not a mark of a good question, and I'm guessing that's why it got downvotes. I'll reproduce my comment here:

> I think you need to check your definitions a bit. If you are asking whether a population of constant size has an equal rate of birth and death, then, yes, by definition; the causes of death for different species will vary, of course. If you are asking about evolutionary stable states...I think you need to check what the definition of such a state is. As-is, the question seems long and rambling and doesn't help a prospective answerer much to find the core of the question. Try to focus in on the most core question you have that is tripping up your thinking.

You did edit a month later, but it just added more content; it did not seem to address the criticism given in the comments (by me and others).

If you think you have a better way to ask the question now, you are certainly welcome to do so.

Comment: I probably have more than 50 years ahead of me. However, I'm not an expert. There aren't that many questions that pop into my head. I'll probably be dead before I get to 10,000 reputation points on any Stack Exchange website even Physics Stack Exchange. That idea is not really an option. Do you think there is another way. Even if I was going to live for ever and that was the only life I've ever known, I would be like I don't want to wait it out. I don't want to do what I don't feel like doing now for that distant future time. I don't want to focus on or wait out distant future times.

Comment: I know how to enjoy the now and adapt to the environment what ever way it is.